# Calculate Total Fee for Accommodation Stay Across Multiple Season Types (Fares)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am developing an accommodation booking platform for a client, that needs to make use of dynamic pricing which is date range based. There are multiple ranges of pricing, known as seasons. For example, High Season, Mid Season and Low Season could have various levels of pricing.

I should also state that I am using CakePHP - although that is not really going to influence it - so I can not necessarily make hardcore MySQL queries but I would much appreciate those types of answers anyway as I may be able to implement a raw MySQL query in Cake.

Here's my scenario:

- A user selects to book accommodation from 2015-08-15 - 2015-09-15
  (for example)
- Peak Season rates run from 2015-08-15 - 2015-08-30 and
- Mid Season rates run from 2015-09-01 - 2015-09-30 (again, as
  example).
- The users stay now falls into two pricing ranges (15 days
  in peak and 15 days in mid)

Pricing is not as simple as x per night, but that is irrelevant right now.

How best would one calculate the pricing for this, assuming that peak costs $50 per night and mid costs $25 per night ? Would a solution that stores date ranges and corresponding costs into arrays (and traversing them) be better than a raw MySQL query that returns the sum of the costs? There are around 5 season types based on booking periods in the year, and I think it could be tricky returning the most relevant one.

Any light shed on this challenge is much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not interested in telling you what's 'best' but I'll give you some pointers

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rates;

CREATE TABLE rates
(season_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,season_type VARCHAR(12) 
,season_start DATE NOT NULL
,season_end DATE NOT NULL 
,rate INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO rates VALUES
(1,'Peak','2015-08-15','2015-08-30',50),
(1,'Mid' ,'2015-09-01','2015-09-30',25);


SELECT * FROM rates;
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+
| season_id | season_type | season_start | season_end | rate |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+
|         1 | Peak        | 2015-08-15   | 2015-08-30 |   50 |
|         2 | Mid         | 2015-09-01   | 2015-09-30 |   25 |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+

SELECT x.*
     , DATEDIFF(season_end,'2015-08-15') 
  FROM rates x 
 WHERE '2015-08-15' >= season_start
 UNION
SELECT x.*
     , DATEDIFF('2015-09-15',season_start) 
  FROM rates x 
 WHERE '2015-09-15' <= season_end;
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------+
| season_id | season_type | season_start | season_end | rate | DATEDIFF(season_end,'2015-08-15') |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------+
|         1 | Peak        | 2015-08-15   | 2015-08-30 |   50 |                                15 |
|         2 | Mid         | 2015-09-01   | 2015-09-30 |   25 |                                14 |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+------------+------+-----------------------------------+
```

Note that August has 31 days

Comment: Thank you for this. This was a good starting base for me. I used your guidance as a springboard, and ended up using PHP's DatePeriod class and storing a rate for each day of the season as to accommodate two ranges of pricing should a booking overlap with two pricing seasons (or even 3). Thank you.